# Functional programming in Scala: find index of an element in a multidimensional list

Tags: arrays, scala, multidimensional-array, indexing, find

I have a two-dimensional list `ll : List[List[T]]` and a function `f : T => Boolean`. I want to find a tuple `(i, j)` of integers such that `f(l(i)(j)) == true` whenever it exists, maybe wrapped inside an `Option`, and would like to do this in the style of functional programming. My current working solution looks as follows:

```
ll.zipWithIndex
  .flatMap{case (l, i) => l.map((_, i)).zipWithIndex}
  .find{case ((l, _), j) => f(l(j))}
  .map{case ((_, i), j) => (i, j)}
```

However, I feel like there should be a nicer way to achieve this - my solution is very cumbersome and doesn't generalize nicely to higher-dimensional arrays. So is there a better way to do this?

Before I go: I'm fully aware this is easily achieved with nested for-loops. So I'm only interested of solutions in the style of functional programming.

Comment: `for` comprehensions are just syntactic sugar for `map()` and `flatMap()` calls. What's non-FP about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any example input to test with, but this appears to work. It returns an `IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)]` collection that *should* (I think) contain all the `(i,j)` pairs where `f(ll(i)(j))` returns **true**.

```
ll.indices
  .flatMap(i => ll(i).indices
                     .collect{case j if f(ll(i)(j)) => (i,j)})
```

Which is pretty much the same as this...

```
for {
  i <- ll.indices
  j <- ll(i).indices
  if f(ll(i)(j))
} yield (i,j)
```

...and, as mentioned in the comments, is fully FP compatible.

Comment: Just one note, accessing by index a **List** is pretty slow it would be better to use `zipWithIndex` and maybe using also **Iterators** to do everything in a single iteration.

Comment: Ugh ... this is worse than _even quadratic_ :/

Answer (score 4):

```
(for { 
  (l, i) <- ll.zipWithIndex
  (e, j) <- l.zipWithIndex
  if f(e)
} yield (i, j)).headOption
```